# Convert an expression to use a specific analytic form

Tags: output-formatting, replacement, special-functions

I have an expression that evaluates to an expression containing multiple `ExpIntegralEi` expressions. However, I would prefer that *Mathematica* use `ExpIntegralE` instead. Is this possible somehow?

(Usually $\operatorname{Ei}(-x) = -E_1(x)$. However, just switching the signs does not work -- I think this relationship is not generally valid for arbitrary complex arguments).

Comment: Apart, perhaps, from branch cuts, it should work, according to [Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExponentialIntegral.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two functions can be related with the appropriate choice of analytical extension at the branch cut.  Replace

```
ExpIntegralEi[x + I y]
```

by

```
-ExpIntegralE[1, -x - I y] + Piecewise[{{-I Pi, y < 0}, {I Pi, y > 0}}]
```

A numerical comparison of the two shows that they are equal.

```
Plot3D[Evaluate[ReIm[ExpIntegralEi[x + I y]]], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
    AxesLabel -> {x, y, Ei}]
```

[image]

```
Plot3D[Evaluate[ReIm[-ExpIntegralE[1, -x - I y] + 
    Piecewise[{{-I Pi, y < 0}, {I Pi, y > 0}}]]], {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},
    AxesLabel -> {x, y, E1}]
```

[image]