# Integrating sinc function over discontinuity

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions, complex

I would like to analytically integrate the sinc function. First of all, if I just perform the integration the following way, everything is as expected:

```
Plot[Integrate[
   Sin[τ π]/(τ π), {τ, -n, t - n}] /. 
   n -> 1, {t, -1, 10}]
```

[image: Simple sinc integration]

As a next step I want to analytically perform the integration. The expression will later have an `Exp` within the integral. So to avoid that *Mathematica* expresses the result as sine integral but rather exponential integral, I add the `Exp` term and set the exponent to zero afterwards:

```
SincInt = Assuming[n ∈ Reals,
   Assuming[τ ∈ Reals,
    Assuming[a ∈ Complexes,
     Assuming[t ∈ Reals,
      Assuming[t > 0,
       Integrate[
        Sin[π τ]/(π τ) Exp[a τ] , {τ, -n, 
        t - n}]]]]]] /. a -> 0
```

By adding all the assumptions I make sure to get no conditional expression (and hence no ambiguity) which is indeed the case:

```
(I (ExpIntegralEi[-I n π] - ExpIntegralEi[I n π] - 
   ExpIntegralEi[-I π (n - t)] + 
   ExpIntegralEi[I π (n - t)]))/(2 π)
```

Now I plot the same thing using this expression and get:

```
Plot[SincInt /. n -> 1, {t, -1, 10}]
```

[image: Analytic sinc integration]

The singularity at zero seems to be a problem. There is a phase jump of $\pi$.

My question is twofold now:

1. How to obtain the correct result?
2. If the result is not unique, why does *Mathematica* not present some conditional expressions and lets me believe everything is fine?

(At first I thought it has to do with $\operatorname{Ei}(z)$ (`ExpIntegralEi`) but after verifying with [Convert an expression to use a specific analytic form](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/101588), I see that the same problem occurs when expressing the result as $\operatorname{E}_1(z)$ (`ExpIntegralE`).

Comment: 1. You are aware that `Sinc[]` is built-in, right? 2. If you set `t > 0` in the assumptions, then `t ∈ Reals` is implied, and superfluous.

Comment: I do, but Mathematica uses $\sin(t)/t$ instead of $\sin(\pi t)/(\pi t)$ ...

Comment: I actually suspect it has something to do with integrating over the singularity. I can derive a function $\operatorname{E_1'}(z) = \operatorname{E_1}(z) + j\pi(\operatorname{sgn}(\Im\{z\})-1)/2 - j\pi(\operatorname{sgn}(\Re\{z\})+1)/2$ which seems to give the right result always. I suspect `ExpIntegralE` does select a branch cut to avoid the singularity, hence the residue $j\pi$ needs to be added back somehow. But I do not understand exactly how and why Mathematica gives me an explicit, unconditional expression which is wrong.

Comment: If $\operatorname{sinc}(t)=\sin(t)/t$ then $\operatorname{sinc}(\pi t)=\sin(\pi t)/(\pi t)$ is what you want.

Answer (score 2):

This is an extended comment, not a solution. If you evaluate

```
Integrate[Sin[τ π]/(τ π), {τ, -n, t - n}] /. n -> 1
```

you get

```
(* SinIntegral[π]/π + SinIntegral[π (-1 + t)]/π *)
```

so I'm a little unclear what you're actually trying to do here? Isn't `SinIntegral` just as "analytic" as the `ExpIntegralEi`'s?

---

Nonetheless, I'm not sure what the problem is in your code, exactly. I suspect that it's the *way* you are trying to do the integral, in the sense that you might have to choose different choices for the exponential function to integrate against before you set `a` to 0.

Let's do some investigations, anyway. First of all, if we collapse all of your `Assumptions` into `1`, we *do* get a `ConditionalExpression`:

```
SincInt = 
  Assuming[{n ∈ Reals, τ ∈ Reals, a ∈ Complexes, t ∈ Reals, t > 0}, 
    Integrate[Sin[π*τ]/(π*τ)*Exp[a*τ], {τ, -n, t - n}]
   ] /. a -> 0
```

[image]

Setting `n == 1`, we can see that when `t` hits `1`, there is a problem. If I just naively plot this function versus plotting the innards without the `ConditionalExpression`, I get this:

```
GraphicsRow@{
  Plot[SincInt /. n -> 1, {t, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> All], 
  Plot[First@SincInt /. n -> 1, {t, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
 }
```

[image]

We can see that the plot stops at `n == 1`, as it should, but if we extract the function from the `ConditionalExpression`, we get the `π`-phase jump, as you noticed.

Finally, let's note that

```
Limit[SincInt, n -> 1] // Expand
(* ConditionalExpression[SinIntegral[π]/π - SinIntegral[π - π t]/π, t <= 1] *)
```

and

```
Plot[Evaluate[Limit[SincInt, n -> 1]], {t, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

yields

[image]

The `SinIntegral` is of course the solution, as we mentioned before.

Comment: Hmm the main reason why I need to use complex exponentials (instead of `SinIntegral`) is that generally $a \neq 0$ (I just set $a=0$ here to have a simple example). Second, what is the difference between my nested assumptions and the collapsed version? Third, the expression does not give enough conditions...

Comment: @divB. As far as I can tell nothing is different, other than that it's nicer looking: it still spits out the `ConditionalExpression1. What do you mean that it doesn't give enough conditions?

Comment: But that's exactly the thing, with my cascaded Assumptions I do ***not*** get a conditional expression! What I mean with enough conditions: The conditional expression above is only valid for $n>t$ or $n<0$. Say $n=2$. Then it is only valid for $t < 2$. What what for $t \geq 2$?

Comment: As for you first point: I copy-and-pasted your code directly into my copy of *Mathematica* 10.0, and it spit out the same `ConditionalExpression` as the version I used in my "answer", so maybe you have lingering definitions or something? As for the second, all I can say is that dealing with complex-valued functions in a computer algebra system is hard (which is to say, I don't know what the problem is).

Comment: Interesting. How can that be? Just opened a new instance and: http://snag.gy/jkn5L.jpg (without setting $a=0$: http://snag.gy/UqfKn.jpg)

Comment: [Here's mine](http://i.stack.imgur.com/KC9qr.png). Could be an issue with the *Student Edition*, or a change between 10.0 and 10.1, or...